# Handle message before event ws nodejs

Tags: node.js, ws

I'm using `ws` version `7.4.0` and I would want to display a console log or perfom operations between the moment where the client is sending a message to the server and before the server fire the `on` event message.

To represent it:

```js
webserver.on('example', function callback(msg){console.log(msg);}); //act before the call of callback
```

client------server---[here]---callback

The only way I see right now would be to use a "root" function before the callback of all my events like this:

```js
function callback(msg){console.log(msg);}
webserver.on('example', function root(msg) {console.log('example msg'); callback(msg);});
```

I don't know if this is a real and/or good solution I really wish to write a clean and organized application.
If someone could give me some advise or a real solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a wrapper for all of your callbacks like so:

```js
function makeCallback(fn) {
  return function(msg) {
    if (!environment.prod) console.log(msg);
    fn(msg)
  };
}

var myCallback = makeCallback(function (msg) {
  // something
});

webserver.on('example', myCallback);
```

Or I think the better solution is to [stream the requets into your stdout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#use-the-nodejs-streams-api) although I don't know the implications of using this method.

And I want to address the naming of your websocket server. Even though a web socket server is technically a web server, it only responds to the websocket protocol and naming it `webserver` could be misleading, I would recommend using the naming like in their documents `wss`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it is how I made it right now, some kind of "middleware". Do you know if the stream option on stdout will then not fire the `on` event ? (it seams it write the entire message receive on the stdout but I would want to write only the road in the end). Thank you for the `wss` naming convention, I already use it in my project but it seems more clear to write `webserver` in my post :s. Thank you @yi fan song

Comment: I'm not too much of a node developer, more front-end, but you should be able to filter the stream like [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/node-js-filter-data-in-streams) or using [stream-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-filter)